# XCode change Comment SYMBOL

Tags: xcode

I *know* how to change key-bindings. My question, which is almost nowhere to find on google: could someone please tell me, how to change the comment-symbols. For example, I want to sometimes define them to be #, sometimes %, sometimes //, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is dictated by the language you are writing in, not by the IDE.

Comment: Yes, I know this, this does not help. How do I access the settings which tell Xcode, when faced with a *.cpp file to comment so and with other filetypes to commen otherwise?